# Notification doesn't open activity

Tags: android, service, notifications, push-notification

I call from service "generateNotification" but after clicking on notification activity doesn't open:

from service:  `generateNotification(getApplicationContext(),contentTitle,contentText,contentText,contentTitle,contentTitle);`

method in the service:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void createNotificationAPI15(Context context, String title, String message,  String ticker_message, String summary_message, String big_message) {
         int id = (new Random()).nextInt(150) + 1;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ListActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Notification notif  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.index2)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setTicker(ticker_message)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(message)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(big_message))
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.index2))
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();

    mNotificationManager.notify(id,  notif);
}
```

in Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
....
 <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/list_act_name" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: Do you use Android Annotations? So is that case check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33763660/2112832

Comment: @CiroMine thanks, but I already found solution, ListActivity was from android package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your PendingIntent like this (it works for me):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ListActivity.class);
// optional flags, such as:
// intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Make sure you pass your ListActivity.class to intent and not android.app.ListActivity.class!

Comment: I think the problem might be that your activity is named ListActivity, make sure that imported ListActivity is YOUR ListActivity, and not android.app.ListActivity.

Comment: Oh My God. This bug was driving me crazy. Surprised how many people name their activities ListActivity. Thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(yourcurrentclass.this, ListActivity.class);
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(yourcurrentclass.this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to make import:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
```